Is the contrapositive of induction useful?
(The idea from this question comes from this document, pg. 14, Example 4.1. That document uses real induction, but my question is about induction on the natural numbers.)
Regular induction says that given $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, if

$I_1$: $1 \in S$,
$I_2$: $n \in S \implies n+1 \in S$,

then $S = \mathbb{N}$.
What I am interested in is the contrapositive of this statement: given $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that we know $S \neq \mathbb{N}$, then by contrapositive either

$\lnot I_1$: $1 \notin S$,
$\lnot I_2$: $n \in S \land n+1 \notin S$.

I have never seen this used, and I cannot find an example where it is more natural to express a proof this way. Is there a case where this is useful or more elegant?

Expressed in another way, if $S \subsetneq N^+$ and $1\in S$ then there exists $x\in S$ such that $x+1\notin S$.

It's elementary that induction is equivalent to the well-ordering property:

If $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb N$, then it has a least element.

The contrapositive of this is:

If $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ has no least element, it is empty.

Proofs based on this principle are very common.  The method is called infinite descent.

If what you want is a application of the contrapositive of the induction principle, then you can prove the following: Some authors includes the uniquiness of $1$ as the natural number which isn't successor of any other, however you can use induction to prove it.
Suppose $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is a natural number such that $k\not\in s(\mathbb{N})$, where $s$ is the successor function, and let $S = \mathbb{N} - \{k\}$. If $n\in S$, then $k\neq s(n)$, for $s(n)\in s(\mathbb{N})$, and therefore $s(n)\in S$. Hence, $S$ is a set that satisfieis $I_2$, but $S\neq\mathbb{N}$. By the contrapositive of induction, it follows that $1\not\in S$. Because the only natural number that isn't in $S$ is the number $k$, it follows that $1 = k$.
This isn't a remarkable result, but it's an example of how the induction principle really characterizes the natural numbers.
